# Multi-Level Views in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-views

The question:

> **Publications**
>   This view has two levels.  The first level will list all members who have associated Journal or Conference Paper records.  The second level lists the titles of the papers for a selected member; the entries in this view are links to the actual papers.

And all I can find from my professor's notes:
[image]

Oh course I'm not asking for you to do it for me, but what does it mean by different levels for a view? And how do you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you Dont bother views you keep hands out of your head!

I think as your instructor requested and used words differently than drupal world I guess. You should prepare one listing (he says view), when an entry selected, load content to another listing (view)  using ajax request, or html from hand crafted  js.

This solution fails if you dont have drupal lesson!